# `pthread_cancel` on Caller Thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Reading this: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html

I'm interested in Knowing if a thread can call `pthread_cancel` on itself? In case it is legal what will happen and will it be similar to calling `pthread_exit()`?

Note: That page doesn't mention anything regarding this interesting case.

Comment: `pthread_exit` exits the thread immediately, it's like a (non-threaded) process calling `exit`. The `pthread_cancel` basically sets a flag that may lead the thread to terminate some time later.

Comment: It seems to be legal; at least [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) has no rule against it.  It doesn't seem like it would be useful, though.

Comment: Better question: are there any circumstances under which I should consider calling `pthread_cancel()`? Answer: probably not.